# Import MP4 media in camtasia studio

Tags: video, mp4, video-codecs, camtasia

I'm editing my video and I wanted to add outro in my video at last.

But the camtasia studio is showing error on importing MP4 format:

> Cannot load file 'filename.mp4'.
>
> It is either unsupported media type or required codecs are not found.

[image]

How can I import this MP4 file format in Camtasia Studio 8?

Comment: "MP4 (AVC/h.264 codecs required, 30 frames per second or less)"

Comment: I have to convert it?

Comment: Install the missing codecs

Comment: I have converted video to h.264 codecs and its now working. Thanks you for helping .